# Image preload and caching not working with javascript or html in FIREFOX

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, browser-cache

Objective: I am making a stop animation with jquery and I need to load 47 images and put them as body background one after another at 450ms delay.

The part that I am having trouble with is that I can't get to cache/preload images correctly so that they switch without blinking etc...

I start the animation in $(window).load(function() {.... so everything should be loaded by then

I have tried a number of ways from stackoverflow and all over the web here are some of them:

NOTE: EVERYTHING WORKS LIKE A CHARM IN GOOGLE CHROME. **FIREFOX IS PROBLEM!**  Site is hosted in wamp for now.

1. Jquery in document load: ( I have tried with plain javascript inserted in the `<script></script>` but no success

   ```
   for (var x = 1; x < 47; x++) 
   {   preloaded[x]     = new Image();
       preloaded[x].src = 'anim_frame' + x + '.png';
   }
   } // later I modifed the code to preload sets of 5 images every 5 frames, so when frame 1 is shown frames 5-10 are loaded and so on...works great in chrome
   ```
2. Putting all the images in html directly as `<img>` tags...not working.
3. jQuery get to image location - not working

I know it can be done, this site made it, why cant we? ;) http://discover.store.sony.com/be-moved/

Comment: why you wait the document load complete to start the load of images?

Comment: No particular reason, i preload the first five images before and then star loading the rest when the animation starts...i tries putting it in doc ready but no success for firefox

Comment: can you post some code?

Comment: I thought that just because $(window).load() is called, this doesn't necessarily mean that your images were loaded. Am I wrong?

Comment: You right it does not mean your images are loaded, and i am not counting on that, i am just starting my animation on that moment.

Comment: Lol it works in both mozila and chrome when i delete all preload code?!?!? i cleard the cache, ofc...

Comment: Well, simply creating `img` elements in Javascript and assigning their `src` attributes won't preload them. In theory, putting all the img elements in the HTML source should work, as long as you mean 47 different ones, not one `<img>` element and rapidly changing its `src` 47 times with Javascript... Can you make a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: I presume the animation is smoother without all the preloading code, because when animating, it will only need to load one picture at a time. With preloading, it may try to load all 47 pictures simultaneously, while also trying to animate. I'd have to experiment with that.

Comment: I just wanted to comment the same thing, removing almost all the preloading code( i still preload 10 images with new Image in doc ready, forgot to remove it) made the animation smooth...it seems i might have started of the wrong foot from the beginning. I wanted to preload the images based on my experience with hover css backgrounds etc...i'll post final results tonight.

Comment: @MrLister: _“Well, simply creating img elements in Javascript and assigning their src attributes won't preload them”_ – oh yes, is _should_. AFAIK every major browser _does_ start to load the resource as soon as you set the `src` attribute of an `Image` element, it does _not_ have to be part of the DOM for that to happen. (This behavior is what countless “image preloader” scripts have relied on since forever …)

Comment: Whats bothering me is that chaching/preloading is what actually made the images blink like they werent loaded? They have 7mb in total, each between 100-500kb and i thought preloading is a must...I am showing the animation in <img tag, just changing the source...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only the following solution worked in all browsers.

Calling jQuery.get on all images in doc.ready and keeping a counter on how many images have loaded. Once they are loaded display the website...in the meanwhile show a nice loader with a percentage of the images loaded ;)